# Given a set of n choose k sets, how many sets in a set of (n+1) choose k sets would include any of m elements and (n+1)?

Tags: combinatorics

Thank you for your help. I'm hoping for a generalized formula or a pointer or two...

For example, given `5 choose 3`:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,5],[1,3,5],[2,3,5],[1,4,5],[2,4,5],[3,4,5]]
```

How many sets in `6 choose 3` would include `6` and any of `m` numbers?

The answer for `m = 3` would be 9

```
[1,2,6],[1,3,6],[2,3,6],[1,4,6],[2,4,6],[3,4,6],[2,5,6],[3,5,6],[4,5,6]
[1,5,6] is the only set that would not include 6 and any of 2, 3 or 4
```

The answer for `m = 2` would be 7

```
[1,2,6],[2,3,6],[1,4,6],[2,4,6],[3,4,6],[2,5,6],[4,5,6]
[1,3,6],[1,5,6],[3,5,6] are the sets that would not include 6 and either 2 or 4
```

I assume the total additional sets would be `(n+1) choose k` subtracted by `n choose k` but
could use some help to learn how to generalize the full answer if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, what you are asking is: how many of the $\binom{n+1}{k}$ combinations of $n+1$ elements contain both $n+1$ and a given $m$-element subset of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

One way to think about this is that you want to pick $k$ elements from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n, n+1\}$, one of which must be $n+1$. So there are $k-1$ elements left to be chosen from $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, and you want at least one of them to be from some $m$-element subset. The number of ways of choosing $k-1$ elements from $n$ such that *none* of them is from that subset is $\binom{n-m}{k-1}$, so the number of ways of choosing such that at least one of them is in that subset is  $\binom{n}{k-1}-\binom{n-m}{k-1}$.

In the example you give with $n=5$, $k=3$, $m=3$, we would get $\binom{5}{2}-\binom{2}{2} = 9$. In your other example, with $n=5$, $k=3$, $m=2$, we get $\binom{5}{2} - \binom{3}{2} = 7$.

Comment: Thank you for your instructive answer!